# Restrict future time in JQuery calendar

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

I am using JQuery calendar for date and time selection in my application. I have restricted the future dates from getting selected but I am not able to restrict future time. Is it due to the scroller which is there to scroll and select time.

Any idea, how can I restrict time.

Thanks in advance.

V.

Answer (score 0):

restrict **maximum** date to **current date**

The below code will return current date

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();

var output = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
```

Now restrict Your calender's maximum date like below:-

```
maxDate: new Date(output)
```

Hope this will help You.